# IIS 10 not showing worker process Current Requests

Tags: iis, asp.net, windows

I have enabled Monitor and Tracing by adding Windows Server 2016 Roles. But IIS not showing me worker process Current Requests when I request a webpage
[image]

How can I view current requests coming in IIS for App pool?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a little too late (10 months later), but the reason you're not getting the "Show requests" command and can't see them is because you're missing the "Request Monitor" feature in your Web Server Role.

Just open the Server Manager,go to Add or Remove Roles and in the wizard make sure you're checking the "Request Monitor" under "Health And Diagnostics", like it's shown in this screen capture:

[image: The image shows the Request Monitor option in the Add Roles Wizard]

After the feature is installed, open again your IIS Manager and you'll see the option to inspect the requests.

HTH

Comment: I have request monitor and tracing installed. But it still doesn't show any req. I didn't restart app. Also I just have enabled failed request tracing for status code 400-599. But failed req tracing shouldn't be related to req monitor? Do I need a app restart ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case enabling Request Monitor wasn't enough, I enabled other options in **Health and Diagnostic** section and restarted the IIS then I was able to see the requests.

[image]